# Should I increase AWS Lambda timeout, or have separate scripts/CRONs for AWS API StartQuery and GetQueryResults?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I currently have an AWS Cloudwatch Event Rule CRON that hits a Lambda responsible for kicking off a CloudWatch Logs Insights StartQuery and GetQueryResults, then sends the results to SNS.

As we know, query results from StartQuery are not instant, therefore I have a conditional statement in the Lambda to check the if the status of GetQueryResults is completed (or whatever, etc.), and if not, sleep for one second and try again:

```
while True:
    get_query_results_response = logs_client.get_query_results(
        queryId=query_id
    )
    status = get_query_results_response.get('status')
    print(f"Query Status: {status}")

    if status in ['Complete', 'Failed', 'Cancelled', 'Timeout']:
        break
    time.sleep(1)

print(f"GetQueryResults Response: {get_query_results_response}")

send_to_sns(sns_client, sns_topic_arn, get_query_results_response.get('results', []))
```

I currently have Lambda timeout set at 15s, and after recently making some query definition changes, it seems to be timing out.

While I could simply increase my Lambda timeout, my lead recommended either having an entirely separate CRON/Lambda/script, one for StartQuery, and another for GetQueryResults like 30 minutes later.  And/or perhaps adding an environment variable and using the same (or again a separate script).

"Sleep" feels bad, but having a separate CRON/Script also sorta feels bad.  My question is in regards to best practices for this relatively straightforward task.

Comment: Looks like there is no way to get notified of the completion of an Insights query, unfortunately. Agree that waiting in Lambda is a huge anti-pattern so don't do it. Perhaps start the query, write the query ID to a DynamoDB table, and schedule a periodic Lambda function to scan the DynamoDB table (for some max number of items) and get updated status/results of the outstanding queries. Delete the query ID from DynamoDB when complete. Find some schedule that works well for your load and your report consumer expectations.

Comment: Rather than writing to DynamoDB, I'd use an SQS queue with delay to trigger another Lambda. Put as much info in the message as you need to identify the query. You're limited to 900 seconds (15 minutes) for the initial delay, but then you can use visibility timeout to delay retries for up to 12 hours. I'd stick with the base 15 minutes (or 5, or 10), and let the redrive mechanism trigger the Lambda until the query is done. Maybe sending to a dead-letter queue after a couple of hours.

Comment: @kdgregory great idea. I did think about SQS here over DynamoDB but neglected to consider SQS delay queues.

Comment: +1 to SQS.  You should be able to [adjust the Message Visibility](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeMessageVisibility.html) to dynamically adjust backoff.